# How to fix Rails radio button collection always returning the last value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an application that has many models, two of them are behaving curiously (Candidate and MarketSegment).

Each entity of class Candidate holds a market_segment_id attribute. We also have a form that allows us to edit instance of Candidate and submit/update via a JSON request.

When I try to render a partial that builds the collection of radio buttons with market segment options to be selected for that candidate within the edit form, I'm always getting the last value/market_segment_id of the radio button list in params hash, that is market_segment_id => '35' every time.

We already tried many different approaches, including:

1) Inspected html to confirm if the 'collection_radio_buttons' helper is generating the right values for each button;

2) Built the loop to create each radio button with its respective attributes manually.

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/forms/market_segments_select', locals: {f: f} %>
```

ruby/erb partial content that generates radio button list

```
<div class="w-100 h4 overflow-scroll overflow-x-hidden bn pt3">
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :market_segment_id, MarketSegment.all, :id, :description_pt do |m| %>
    <div class="w-100 mb2 market_segment__radio-group">
      <%= m.radio_button %>
      <%= m.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

html generated by the partial

```
<div class="w-100 h4 overflow-scroll overflow-x-hidden bn pt3">
  <input type="hidden" name="candidate[market_segment_id]" value="" />
    <div class="w-100 mb2 market_segment__radio-group">
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="candidate[market_segment_id]" id="candidate_market_segment_id_1" />
      <label for="candidate_market_segment_id_1">Agronegócio e Bioenergia</label>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 mb2 market_segment__radio-group">
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="candidate[market_segment_id]" id="candidate_market_segment_id_2" />
      <label for="candidate_market_segment_id_2">Alimentos</label>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 mb2 market_segment__radio-group">
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="candidate[market_segment_id]" id="candidate_market_segment_id_3" />
      <label for="candidate_market_segment_id_3">Auditoria</label>
    </div>
...and so on until market_segment_id = 35
```

params

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Sgpo39Lo...==", "candidate"=>{"avatar"=>"", ..., "market_segment_id"=>"35", ...}, "commit"=>"Atualizar", "id"=>"8"}
```

controller action

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @candidate.update(candidate_params)
        create_candidate_skill_tags

        format.html do
          redirect_to admin_candidate_path(@candidate),
                      notice: 'Candidato atualizado com sucesso'
        end
        format.json { render json: @candidate, status: :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json do
          render json: @candidate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Regardless of the radio button I select the params always get market_segment_id => '35' (that is the last record of the MarketSegment table.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing. You could do something like this

```
  def create_candidate_skill_tags 
     new_skill_tags_from_params.map do |skill_text| 
      @candidate.skill_tags << SkillTag.where(id: 
    skill_text).first_or_create
  end
 end


<label for="users"><strong>Your Form</strong></label>
<div class="custom-select form-control pull-right">
 <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:market_segment_id, MarketSegment.all, :id, 
    :description, 
  checked: @candidate.market_segments.map(&:id)) do |b| %>    
    <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

also you need in your candidate.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :market_segments, foreign_key: :candidate_id
```

and in market_segment.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :candidates
```

ensure you have `:candidate_id` column in your db. or any how you did it.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem, @Nsikan. I did it with the same approach and still nothing.

Comment: let's see the controller's action

Comment: Just updated the question with the controller's action, @Nsikan.

Comment: let me see this function create_candidate_skill_tags

Comment: can you do this as well params.require(:candidate).permit!

Comment: let me see this function create_candidate_skill_tags

Comment: name="candidate[market_segment_id]" from generated form. your name is getting Id s  but in `create_candidate_skill_tags`  `@candidate.skill_tags << SkillTag.where(name: skill_text).first_or_create` is checking for where SkillTag mactches name. should be `@candidate.skill_tags << SkillTag.where(id: skill_text).first_or_create`

Comment: I think this function has nothing to do with what's going on, @Nsikan.

I explicitly state in the question description that I'm having an issue with market_segment, that is completely different from skilltags.

Comment: ok I see what of `candidate_params` ?  actually I have use it with HABTM and it  works fine. if you are interested I can give you my source codes.

Comment: All candidate's attributes, including :market_segment_id.

Comment: In my case, I use it with has_one :market_segment (on Candidate class).

Comment: has_one has a convention of creating the actual association in controller action e.g  ` @admin = current_admin
    @company = Company.create(company_params)
    @company.companyadmin_id= @admin.id
    @admin.company = @company
    @company.save`  You need to manually enable the association. find the market_segment and associate it.

Comment: `@ms = MarketSegment.find(params[:market_segment_id]) then @candidate.market_segment = @ms `

Comment: That's true, but it is not the problem. It is already updating the market_segment_id with the value from params.
The question is that params is getting the wrong value from the form and I don't know why but it is always the value of the last radio button.

Comment: use the form in my answer.

Comment: one more thing, remove it from the partial. create a the form in the edit view.